# How to find the exact word using a regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

Consider the following code snippet:

```
String input = "Print this";
System.out.println(input.matches("\\bthis\\b"));
```

Output

```
false
```

What could be possibly wrong with this approach? If it is wrong, then what is the right solution to find the exact word match?

PS: I have found a variety of similar questions here but none of them provide the solution I am looking for.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you use the `matches()` method, it is trying to match the entire input. In your example, the input *"Print this"* doesn't match the pattern because the word *"Print"* isn't matched.

So you need to add something to the regex to match the initial part of the string, e.g.

```
.*\\bthis\\b
```

And if you want to allow extra text at the end of the line too:

```
.*\\bthis\\b.*
```

Alternatively, use a `Matcher` object and use `Matcher.find()` to find matches *within* the input string:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\bthis\\b");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Print this");
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output:

```
this
```

If you want to find multiple matches in a line, you can call `find()` and `group()` repeatedly to extract them all.

Answer (score 12):

Full example method for matcher:

```
public static String REGEX_FIND_WORD="(?i).*?\\b%s\\b.*?";

public static boolean containsWord(String text, String word) {
    String regex=String.format(REGEX_FIND_WORD, Pattern.quote(word));
    return text.matches(regex);
}
```

Explain:

1. **(?i)** - ignorecase
2. **.*?** - allow (optionally) any characters before
3. **\b** - word boundary
4. **%s** - variable to be changed by String.format (quoted to avoid regex
   errors)
5. **\b** - word boundary
6. **.*?** - allow (optionally) any characters after

Comment: `.*` is already _any character zero or more times_ so you don't need the `?`.

Answer (score 5):

For a good explanation, see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html

> myString.matches("regex") returns true or false depending whether the
>   string can be matched entirely by the regular expression. It is
>   important to remember that String.matches() only returns true if the
>   entire string can be matched. In other words: "regex" is applied as if
>   you had written "^regex$" with start and end of string anchors. This
>   is different from most other regex libraries, where the "quick match
>   test" method returns true if the regex can be matched anywhere in the
>   string. If myString is abc then myString.matches("bc") returns false.
>   bc matches abc, but ^bc$ (which is really being used here) does not.

This writes "true":

```
String input = "Print this";
System.out.println(input.matches(".*\\bthis\\b"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use groups to find the exact word. Regex API specifies groups by parentheses. For example:

`A(B(C))D`

This statement consists of three groups, which are indexed from 0.

- 0th group - ABCD
- 1st group - BC
- 2nd group - C

So if you need to find some specific word, you may use two methods in `Matcher` class such as: `find()` to find statement specified by regex, and then get a `String` object specified by its group number:

```
String statement = "Hello, my beautiful world";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Hello, my (\\w+).*");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(statement);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

The above code result will be "beautiful"

Comment: `find()` returns a boolean value indicating whether the match succeeded or not.  You should *never* call `find()` and ignore the result.  Ditto for `matches()` and `lookingAt()`.  Also, the group numbers are indexed from one, not zero.  The first "group", `group(0)`, is an artificial one representing the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `searchString` going to be *regular expression*? if not simply use [String.contains(CharSequence s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Comment: Be aware that when you pass `"this"` to the `contains` method, it also returns true, if the input string is `"isthisnice"` without spaces. So you do not know, if the match is the exact word.

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(input.matches(".*\\bthis$"));

Also works. Here the .* matches anything before the space and then this is matched to be word in the end.