# Java: Discover if a word is present in a string

Tags: java, string

I want to find out if a string is a precise word, but for example if I do it this way:

```
String s1="Welcome";
String s ="Welcomes to Tutorialspoint.com";
System.out.println(s.contains(s1));
```

It returns true, but I want you to give me back false, because in the variable `s` with the word `Welcomes` and not the word `Welcome` of `s1`.
How do I proceed?

Comment: Take a look at regular expression and word boundarys

Comment: You want to find out whether the string **is** a precise word or **contains** a precise word?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
Arrays.asList(s.split("\\s+")).contains(s1)
```

You can modify this solution to fit your needs by adapting the regex that is used for splitting. For instance, if you wanted to split on anything that isn't a word character (i.e. punctuation and whatnot), you could use `\W+`.

Comment: His question isn't clear. This approach will work, but not if he wants to ignore punctuation or case. (Sounds like a job for Java 8!)

Comment: @chrylis It's very easy to modify this solution to cover all of that.

Comment: What about if I would like to find `word` in `Some simple word. And another "word".`?

Comment: @Pshemo Then you can split on `\W+`.

Comment: It might be elegant, but this is only good for very simple cases, will catch you out if you do not understand how it is working, has the same (or greater) overhead as using  a matcher (as far as the regex is concerned), creates an Array and a List, performs 3 functions on one line for brevity not clarity and doesn't teach Enzo anything about how someone might really use Java. It is a very popular answer though!

Answer (score 3):

Use `.matches()` with the following regex:

```
System.out.println(s.matches(".*\\b" + s1 + "\\b.*"));
```

See [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464261/how-to-find-the-exact-word-using-a-regex-in-java) for more info.

Also, if you want to ignore case, you can do this:

```
System.out.println(s.toUpperCase().matches(".*\\b" + s1.toUpperCase() + "\\b.*"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can split the sentence and then compare each of the words with `s1`.

```
String s1="Welcome";
String s ="Welcomes to Tutorialspoint.com";
String[] split = s.split(" ");
for (String s : split) {
  if (s.equals(s1)) {
    System.out.println(s);
    break; //optional
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
s.matches(".*\\b" + s1 + "\\b.*")
```

using the `"\\b"` to find a word boundary.

Comment: This won't work, you will need ".*" before the first "\\b" and after the second "\\b", otherwise it will only return true if s.equals(s1).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464261/how-to-find-the-exact-word-using-a-regex-in-java

Comment: Good point.  Only realized that after I saw your post.  Regex corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) to tokenize the String into constituent words. Then compare each word with the s1.

Comment: StringTokenizer is deprecated.

Comment: Can you post a link to the documentation that says its deprecated please? I think StreamTokenizer is deprecated not StringTokenizer. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/deprecated-list.html#class

Comment: From the link you posted: *"`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."*

Comment: So does not have `deprecated` word, but nearly.

Comment: Thanks. So just to be clear, it is NOT deprecated but discouraged. Cool, didnt know that. Learnt something new today!

Comment: Okay, sure. It's not *officially* considered to be deprecated perhaps, but it's use is certainly discouraged.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983856/why-is-stringtokenizer-deprecated

Answer (score 0):

For something a little more advanced than using simple String parsing and/or regular expressions you could take a look at how [Lucene parses and analyses](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/Analyzer.html) text.

I suspect its more than you need and it adds a dependency to do something that in your case is quite simple.