# How to match an exact match in a string using Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to check if a string contains an exact match. 
For example:
String str = "This is my string that has -policy and -p"

How can I do the following:

```
if (str.contains("-p")) {  // Exact match to -p not -policy
System.out.println("This is -p not -policy");

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the exact word using a regex in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464261/how-to-find-the-exact-word-using-a-regex-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To differentiate the -p this below solution simply works. If we add /b in the front then the "test-p" kind of word will also be matched.

```
String source = "This is -p not -policy";
System.out.println("value is " + Pattern.compile(" -p\\b").matcher(source).find());
```

Comment: Simply put, Thanks for your answer. I didn't need the space before -p ("-p\\b") worked for me. QQ I thought \b char \b will give me the exact char in the middle, but it doesn't. can you explain it if you don't mind?

Comment: \bis\b means it will defintely match in the string " this is -p not -policy ". But we are having metacharacter hypen ('-') at the begining so it is looking for some character before hypen. Suppose in the string "this is t-p not -policy" it will match the word 't-p'

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
(?<!\w)\-p(?!\w)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rZ4vO7/1)

Which means:

- `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind for any word character (A-Za-z0-9_) so
  if it will be preceded by &*%^%^ it will match anyway,
- `\-p` - -p
- `(?!\w)` negative lookahead for any word character (A-Za-z0-9_), as
  above

Another solution could be also:

```
(?<=\s)\-p(?=\s)
```

then there must be space char (' ') before and anfter `-p`

Implementation in Java with [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = "This is my string that has -policy and -p";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)\\-p(?!\\w)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sample);
        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(sample.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: regex works, but I can't get to work with .matches or contains. can you provide the full code?

Comment: @Moe I updated answer with code, .matches returns true only if whole string match with regex, contains doesn't work with regex

Comment: Thanks so much for your prompt responses, but I have too many lines of  syntax to verify the possible outcome of that one line, so i am looking for the shortest syntax.  Pattern.compile(" -p\\b").matcher(source).find()); I hope I can select 2 correct answer!! Thanks again!!

Comment: @Moe no problem, we choose most useful answer, that all. Just to your knowledge, my answer could be shortened to `Pattern.compile("(?<!\\w)\\-p(?!\\w)").matcher(sample).find()`, it also use Pattern and Matcher, and both class are worth to learn about.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
String str = "This is my string that has -policy and -p";
for(String i:str.split(" ")){
   if(i.equals("-p")){ // now you are checking the exact match
     System.out.println("This is -p not -policy");
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for the shortest way to check if the string has what I am looking for. thanks again!!