# Regular Expression to match a string that does not contain specific string in Java

Tags: java

I need a regular expression that matches a substring in string `/*exa*/mple*/` ,

the matched string must be `/*exa*/` not `/*exa*/mple*/`.

It also must not contain `"*/"` in it.

I have tried these regex:

1. `"/\\*[.*&&[^*/]]\\*/"`  ,
2. `"/\\*.*&&(?!^*/$)\\*/"`

but im not able to get the exact solution.

Comment: Try this [How to find the exact word using a regex in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464261/how-to-find-the-exact-word-using-a-regex-in-java)

Comment: Simplest would be to use two regex's, match rexexp1 && ~ regexp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to pick out comments from a text.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*.*?\\*/");
Matcher m = p.matcher("/*ex*a*/mple*/and/*more*/ther*/");
while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
/\*[^\*\/\*]+\*/   --> anything that is in between (including) "/*" and "*/"
```

Here is a sample:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("/\\*[^\\*\\/\\*]+\\*/");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("/*exa*/mple*/");
    while (m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**

> /*exa*/