# How to search word in String text, this word end "." or "," in java

Tags: java, string, search

someone can help me with code?
How to search word  in String text, this word end   "." or "," in java

I don't want search like this to find it

```
String word = "test.";

String wordSerch = "I trying to tasting the Artestem test.";

String word1 = "test,"; // here with ","

String word2 = "test."; // here with "."

String word3 = "test";  //here without 

//after i make string array and etc...

if((wordSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(word1))||
   (wordSearch.equalsIgnoreCase(word2))||
   (wordSearh.equalsIgnoreCase(word3))) {
}

if (wordSearch.contains(gramer)) 
//it's not working because the word Artestem  will contain test too, and I don't need it
```

Comment: Have you done some research? Based on your needs, `contains`, `startWith`, ... from String or a Regex will do it, there is enough existing source I believe to find what you need

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  You may find `String.endsWith()` useful though.

Comment: What about using regex (as pointed by AxelH)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464261/how-to-find-the-exact-word-using-a-regex-in-java

Comment: Explain what you want because this is not clear. Adding some example is always a good idea. But I am pretty sure this is a simple search that could be answer by Google

Comment: thank you
The complex question :)
My second language is English so sorry for my words non-clear

I am researching within the text through the words stored in a Array, so looking for a way to shorten the code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `matches(Regex)` function with a String

```
String word = "test.";
boolean check = false;
if (word.matches("\w*[\.,\,]") {
    check = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\btest\\b").matcher(wordSearch);
if (matcher.find()) {
}
```

`\\b\\b` will match only a word. So `"Artestem"` will not match in this case.
`matcher.find()` will return `true` if there is a word `test` in your sentence and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

```
String stringToSearch = "I trying to tasting the Artestem test.   test,";

Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("test[.,]");
Matcher m = p1.matcher(stringToSearch);

while (m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group());   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is a word? E.g.:

1. Is '5' a word?
2. Is '漢語' a word, or two words?
3. Is 'New York' a word, or two words?
4. Is 'Kraftfahrzeughaftpflichtversicherung' (meaning "automobile liability insurance") a word, or 3 words?

For some languages you can use `Pattern.compile("[^\\p{Alnum}\u0301-]+")` for split words. Use `Pattern#split` for this.

I think, you can find word by this pattern:

```
String notWord = "[^\\p{Alnum}\u0301-]{0,}";
Pattern.compile(notWord  + "test" + notWord)`
```

See also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your String in an Array divided by words(with "split"), and search on that array , checking the last character of the words(charAt) with the character that you want to find.

```
String stringtoSearch = "This is a test.";
String whatIwantToFind = ",";

String[] words =  stringtoSearch.split("\\s+");
for (String word : words) {
    if (whatIwantToFind.equalsignorecas(word.charAt(word.length()-1);)) {
        System.out.println("FIND");

    }
}
```